# Where in my PWA should I be loading a somewhat large JSON file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA that its main function is to display a list of items with a search box and sort-by buttons on top of each column. The list is never altered (no CRUD sections), and the search box is the only one that mutates its state.

The JSON in question currently has 1300+ items, each record with 26 columns total, out of which only 4 are taken for the list I mentioned above (the rest of the columns are used in other parts of the app).

I'm currently loading the JSON file in my Vuex store with something like this:

```
actions: {
  async loadData({commit}) 
  {
    const json = await import('data_full.json').then(module => module.default)
    commit('setData', json)
  }
},
mutations: {
  setData(state, payload) {
    state.jsonData = payload
  },
}
```

Which is then used in my App.vue:

```
mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch('loadData')
},
```

This works perfectly fine, the app works as I expect it. However, I'm wondering if I'm loading the file in the right place, or if the initial data should be handled differently altogether. The JSON file will eventually become much bigger and I'm already noticing an increasing load time when the app is first opened as I add more records.

I've considered the possibility of using IndexedDB instead, and I'm currently testing splitting the JSON file in two (one for the whole set of items, and another with only the 4 fields necessary for the list). My goal is to have faster "first paint" times, although I'm aware that's limited given the size of the dataset I'm using.

Should I be loading the JSON file elsewhere? Or be loaded differently into the Vuex store?

Comment: Is paginating the data an option? EDIT: If the answer is no, then you should change it to yes :)

Comment: Alternatively, once loaded you could set data in `localStorage` and 
only request the diff based on what the user has in storage.

Comment: I'm paginating the data, yes, although all of it is being loaded onto the Vuex store in one swing. Separating the chunks in pages has helped with the overall performance of the app, but the initial load (before the first components are shown) remains equal.

Comment: If you only ever showed 10 or 20 items at a time, then you could make tiny requests that load small pieces of your large JSON file based on filters/search input that would speed up your initial load drastically. Client-side pagination, as you've seen, is not a good long term choice unless the data set is static and small (e.g. virtually never)

Comment: I prefer the extra 2 seconds of initial load time on certain types of non-website SPAs over sending many requests to the server (and waiting for each response), even for larger data sets, just as long as bandwidth is not a concern.  Maybe it won't scale well, but if you have an app that sends a 1000 row result and will only ever have 5 users, I prefer to send data up front instead of making them wait every 20 rows. There are ways to mitigate the wait too, but it's simply easier not to bother if the situation is right. Depends on the bandwidth/app. Also agree with the `localStorage` suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I do this sort of thing all the time. A typical example might be a list of US zip codes and cities, about 7MB.

I would fetch that in the background from within the service worker. I would store or cache it in IndexedDB since that is a very large database and is available in the service worker and client.

I use localForage as my IDB library b/c it is stupid simple and I like simple.

localforage.setItem("zipcodes", zipcodes).then(...)

localforage.getItem("zipcodes").then(...)

I sometimes fetch data like this and render entire websites in the service worker. I wrote about this technique in a demo app I did for a conference last October,

https://love2dev.com/pwa/pubcon/